# Showing that the map $n:G \rightarrow G$, that is multiplication by $n$, induces multiplication on $Ext(H,G)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to show that the map $n:G \rightarrow G$ induces the map $n:Ext(H,G) \rightarrow Ext(H,G)$, where $H$ and $G$ are abelian groups.

Since $Ext(H,G)=H^{1}(F,G)$ for any free resolution $F$ of $H$, I am just using the simplest free resolution $0 \rightarrow F_{1} \rightarrow F_{0} \rightarrow H \rightarrow 0$ as discussed on page 195 in Hatcher.

I dualize this free resolution by applying $Hom(-,G)$ to get

$0 \leftarrow F^{*}_1 \leftarrow F^{*}_0 \leftarrow H^{*} \leftarrow 0$.

> From here I am unsure how to the map $G \rightarrow G$ to a map $Ext(H,G) \rightarrow Ext(H,G)$.

Comment: What is $G\:\:$?

Comment: Any abelian group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $G$ is some abelian group, and $A$ is another abelian group, then composing a homomorphism $\phi: A \to G$ with $n: G \to G$ gives a homomorphism

$$ \mathrm{Hom}(A, G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A, G)$$

which is also multiplication by $n$ on the abelian group $\mathrm{Hom}(A, G)$, since by definition $n\cdot \phi$ is the homomorphism $(a \mapsto n\phi(a))$. Applying this idea to a chain complex $C_\bullet$ gives a morphism of complexes

$$ \mathrm{Hom}(C_\bullet, G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(C_\bullet, G). $$

Morphisms of complexes lead to homomorphisms between (co)homology groups. In your case, we arrive at

$$ n: \mathrm{Ext}(H, G) \to \mathrm{Ext}(H, G)$$